# Android SDK setting proxy with ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, proxy, setting

Where can I find android SDK proxy setting?

I am working with ubuntu, thanks in advance.

All what I have is in below screen

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can only check this on my mac at the moment.  The settings are stored in `~/.android/androidtool.cfg`

My settings currently look like:

```
### Settings for Android Tool
#Thu Dec 08 12:22:00 GMT 2011
http.proxyPort=8080
http.proxyHost=127.0.0.1
sdkman.show.update.only=true
sdkman.ask.adb.restart=false
sdkman.force.http=false
```

So try manually editing that file (assuming it's in the same place on ubuntu)

Comment: The file wasnt there by default in ubuntu but I created it, entered the values and worked !

Answer (score 2):

I just modified android tool

here the [gits](https://gist.github.com/lguzzon/5532845)

```
#!/bin/sh
# Copyright 2005-2007, The Android Open Source Project
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

SS_HTTP_PROXY_HOST=${http_proxy%:*}
SS_HTTP_PROXY_HOST=${SS_HTTP_PROXY_HOST##*/}

SS_HTTP_PROXY_PORT=${http_proxy##*:}
SS_HTTP_PROXY_PORT=${SS_HTTP_PROXY_PORT%%/*}

SS_HTTPS_PROXY_HOST=${https_proxy%:*}
SS_HTTPS_PROXY_HOST=${SS_HTTPS_PROXY_HOST##*/}

SS_HTTPS_PROXY_PORT=${https_proxy##*:}
SS_HTTPS_PROXY_PORT=${SS_HTTPS_PROXY_PORT%%/*}

# Set up prog to be the path of this script, including following symlinks,
# and set up progdir to be the fully-qualified pathname of its directory.
prog="$0"
while [ -h "${prog}" ]; do
    newProg=`/bin/ls -ld "${prog}"`
    newProg=`expr "${newProg}" : ".* -> \(.*\)$"`
    if expr "x${newProg}" : 'x/' >/dev/null; then
        prog="${newProg}"
    else
        progdir=`dirname "${prog}"`
        prog="${progdir}/${newProg}"
    fi
done
oldwd=`pwd`
progdir=`dirname "${prog}"`
cd "${progdir}"
progdir=`pwd`
prog="${progdir}"/`basename "${prog}"`
cd "${oldwd}"

jarfile=sdkmanager.jar
frameworkdir="$progdir"
if [ ! -r "$frameworkdir/$jarfile" ]
then
    frameworkdir=`dirname "$progdir"`/tools/lib
fi
if [ ! -r "$frameworkdir/$jarfile" ]
then
    frameworkdir=`dirname "$progdir"`/framework
fi
if [ ! -r "$frameworkdir/$jarfile" ]
then
    echo `basename "$prog"`": can't find $jarfile"
    exit 1
fi


# Check args.
if [ debug = "$1" ]; then
    # add this in for debugging
    java_debug=-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8050,suspend=y
    shift 1
else
    java_debug=
fi

java_cmd="java"

# Mac OS X needs an additional arg, or you get an "illegal thread" complaint.
if [ `uname` = "Darwin" ]; then
    os_opts="-XstartOnFirstThread"
else
    os_opts=
fi

proxy_opts=
if [ ! -z "$SS_HTTP_PROXY_HOST" ] ; then
    proxy_opts=$proxy_opts" -Dhttp.proxyHost=${SS_HTTP_PROXY_HOST} -Dhttp.proxyPort=${SS_HTTP_PROXY_PORT}"
fi
if [ ! -z "$SS_HTTPS_PROXY_HOST" ] ; then
    proxy_opts=$proxy_opts" -Dhttps.proxyHost=${SS_HTTPS_PROXY_HOST} -Dhttps.proxyPort=${SS_HTTPS_PROXY_PORT}"
fi

if [ `uname` = "Linux" ]; then
    export GDK_NATIVE_WINDOWS=true
fi

if [ "$OSTYPE" = "cygwin" ] ; then
    jarpath=`cygpath -w  "$frameworkdir/$jarfile"`
    jarpath="$jarpath;"`cygpath -w  "$frameworkdir/swtmenubar.jar"`
    progdir=`cygpath -w  "$progdir"`
else
    jarpath="$frameworkdir/$jarfile:$frameworkdir/swtmenubar.jar"
fi

# Get the current content of java.ext.dirs so that we can add to it instead of replacing
javaExtDirs=`"${java_cmd}" -jar "${frameworkdir}/archquery.jar" java.ext.dirs`

# Figure out the path to the swt.jar for the current architecture.
# if ANDROID_SWT is defined, then just use this.
# else, if running in the Android source tree, then look for the correct swt folder in prebuilt
# else, look for the correct swt folder in the SDK under tools/lib/
swtpath=""
if [ -n "$ANDROID_SWT" ]; then
    swtpath="$ANDROID_SWT"
else
    vmarch=`"${java_cmd}" -jar "${frameworkdir}/archquery.jar"`
    if [ -n "$ANDROID_BUILD_TOP" ]; then
        osname=`uname -s | tr A-Z a-z`
        swtpath="${ANDROID_BUILD_TOP}/prebuilts/tools/${osname}-${vmarch}/swt"
    else
        swtpath="${frameworkdir}/${vmarch}"
    fi
fi

if [ ! -d "$swtpath" ]; then
    echo "SWT folder '${swtpath}' does not exist."
    echo "Please export ANDROID_SWT to point to the folder containing swt.jar for your platform."
    exit 1
fi

# need to use "java.ext.dirs" because "-jar" causes classpath to be ignored
exec "$java_cmd" \
    -Xmx256M $os_opts $proxy_opts $java_debug \
    -Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="$progdir" \
    -classpath "$jarpath:$swtpath/swt.jar" \
    com.android.sdkmanager.Main "$@"
```