# Google API is not showing in Android SDK Manager in Ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, sdk, proxy

I have Android SDK Manager Revision 20.0. I have Ubuntu 12.04. I am in my office and there is a proxy configuration URL linked to a ".pac" file through which Internet is connected.

In Android SDK Manager, only Android SDK Tools is showing as "Installed" and no other packages or APIs are shown. I have tried to reload it many times but it's not coming.

I have downloaded the ".pac" file and updated the proxy in Android SDK Manager and tried with that. Also with "Forcing 'https://' to 'http://'. But nothing is working.

Please suggest me what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Problem solved. I went to .android/androidtools.cfg file and updated the Proxy port and Proxy Address manually. It cant be modified properly in Tools->Options . So, it's convenient.

Answer (score 0):

A proxy is usually not so difficult to use, you just have to set an IP/URL and a port.

You can set a proxy for your android sdk manager in

```
Tools > Options
```

or just [download the SDK components separately](http://qdevarena.blogspot.it/2010/05/download-android-sdk-standalone-for.html) .

Comment: I have mentioned that I have tried to update the proxy but it's not working. Can you tell me how to update proxy for Ubuntu. Because ADB for Android SDK is taking default proxy while the proxy for my Firefox is a configuration URL linked to a ".pac" file. How to update proxy with ".pac" file, you can also tell me.

Comment: @soham.m17 you have reloaded the list after setting the proxy?

Comment: @soham.m17 there is also this solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9994299/android-sdk-setting-proxy-with-ubuntu